# Transfer data from DB2 to Sql Server and update success flag in DB2

Tags: transactions, db2, middleware

I have a requirement of transferring data from DB2 table to Sql Server and update the flag of IsSuccess to true back in DB2. This transaction should be **atomic**.

If the data gets transferred to Sql Server, but the IsSuccess flag of DB2 table could not be updated, the first operation should be rolled-back.

Could anyone provide me a solution for this requirement.
Is there is any custom middleware for this kind of requirement.

Comment: SQL Server has federation features -- maybe it makes sense to use that.  Other than that you are talking about an ETL -- there is a ton of tools out there to do ETL work and as such this should probably be close as opinion based.

Comment: I am looking for non-ETL solutions. Perhaps a custom-windows based service or any queue based solution.

Comment: I don't understand... a "custom" solution would not exist before it is built.

Comment: I meant a windows based service solution. I do not want to use ETL based approach.

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand what you mean.  ETL just means any process that takes from one source and writes to another source.  Since this is what you are going to do it must be an ETL process at some level.  Maybe you think ETL is a specific middleware product?  In any case, I don't understand that.  Then you say you want a queue based solution.  That can mean many things since a queue can be used at any interface and any ETL can have many interfaces depending on how you look at it.  Basically your question is both specific and general.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Also I don't think you mean "atomic".  I think you mean "fault tolerant".  Atomic is impossible you are using two different DB systems -- can't be atomic.

Comment: @Hogan Distributed transactions, homo- or heterogeneous, are indeed a thing, but implementation is non-trivial -- [here's one example](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/research/tr/tr696.pdf).